# Skipping elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

My code is skipping the 3rd and 4th elif statement. Instead of plotting red or purple dots for values that fall between 86 and 106 and then values between 106 and 201, they are plotting maroon which is the else statement. Why is my code skipping over those two conditions? It reads the first two elif statements as I wish so I do no understand what is happening with the last two.

```
if zlist < '55':
    plt.scatter(x = xlist, y = ylist, color = 'green')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
    
elif '55' < zlist < '71':
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'yellow')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
    
elif '71' < zlist < '86':
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'orange')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
             
elif '86' < zlist < '106':
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'red')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
             
elif '106' < zlist < '201':
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'purple')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
             
elif zlist > '201':
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'maroon')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
```

Comment: What is `zlist`? Are you aware that in the statement `zlist < '55'` you compare it against a string?

Comment: No string is greater than `'86'` and less than `'106'`. Strings are compared lexicographically, and `'8'` is greater than `'1'`.

Comment: If your `zlist` values are numbers, then comparing them to strings is meaningless.  If they're strings, then they are being compared in lexicographic (alphabetic) order, which is not at all the same as numeric order.  For example, there is no string that is greater than '86', yet less than '106'.

Comment: Strings do not sort the same as numbers. Using string comparisons,  `'100'` is less than `'55'`.

Comment: Thank you all! I was aware I was comparing a list instead of integers but I did not know that strings compared by lexicographic vs numeric. I understand now!

Comment: Also, not sure if you mean to, but those ranges are non-overlapping.   55, 61, 86, 106 doesn't match anything.

Comment: Question needs to share a sample zlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zlist = int(zlist)
if zlist < 55:
    plt.scatter(x = xlist, y = ylist, color = 'green')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
    
elif 55 < zlist <= 71:
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'yellow')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
    
elif 71 < zlist <= 86:
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'orange')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
             
elif 86 < zlist <= 106:
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'red')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
             
elif 106 < zlist <= 201:
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'purple')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
             
elif zlist > 201:
    plt.scatter(x =xlist, y =ylist, color = 'maroon')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
    plt.text(xlist, ylist, zlist)
```

You are attempting to use comparisons on strings, but Python won't perform numeric comparisons on strings. It will instead attempt to sort/compare them alphabetically, which will result in unexpected behavior. You can fix this by casting Zlist to an integer and performing integer comparisons instead.

You might also want to adjust the elif comparisons to include <= for the second breakpoint. Otherwise, numbers such as 71, 86, 106, 201, etc. won't be matched by any of the elif blocks and will drop straight to the else block.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand my mistakes now

Comment: You probably want `<= 55`

Comment: @PewPewPanda If the answer worked for you, please accept it (green checkmark).